# Passive Numerical Decrease

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a representation of a water boiler and I want to make it so that when I turn off the heat then the temperature inside the boiler decreases. The boiler increases in temperature by 0.5 degrees every 0.25th of a second but I also want it to decrease when the heat is off by 0.5 degrees every second. This decrease needs to cap out at 18 degrees and not go any further then that. If you guys have any suggestions that would be well appreciated. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Boiler Temperature Control</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: black;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .container {
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 600px;
      padding: 20px;
    }

    h1 {
      font-size: 36px;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .image-container {
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 40px;
    }

    img {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 500px;
      height: auto;
    }

    .btn {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: #8B4513;
      color: white;
      border: none;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      margin: 10px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    }

    .btn:hover {
      background-color: #CD853F;
    }

    .temperature-container, .heater-status-container {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: 20px;
    }

    .temperature-container h2, .heater-status-container h2 {
      margin-top: 0;
    }

    .temperature-container p, .heater-status-container p {
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 24px;
    }

    .heater-status-container p {
      font-size: 16px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="https://www.canberratimes.com.au/images/transform/v1/crop/frm/32suSVsqH3pdw6NJyh92X9D/f330b4ee-4f0b-4cba-bd95-5dce19be6c00.jpg/r0_0_3000_2003_w3000_h2003_fmax.jpg" alt="Steam Train">
    <p>
      Current temperature: <span id="temperature"></span> degrees Celsius
    </p>
    <p>Heater status: <span id="heater-status"></span></p>
    <button class="btn" onclick="toggleHeater()">Toggle Heater</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="playSteamWhistle()">Steam Whistle</button>
    <audio id="heater-audio" src="bonfire-hq-6991.mp3"></audio>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
const steamWhistleSound = new Audio('sfx6-whistlescreemtrain-33567.mp3');
let boilerTemperature = 18;
let boilerHeater = false;
let temperatureIntervalId = null;

function updateTemperature() {
  const temperatureElement = document.getElementById("temperature");
  temperatureElement.innerText = boilerTemperature;
}

function updateHeaterStatus() {
  const heaterStatusElement = document.getElementById("heater-status");
  heaterStatusElement.innerText = boilerHeater ? "on" : "off";
}

function startTemperatureIncrease() {
  temperatureIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
    if (boilerHeater && boilerTemperature < 110) {
      boilerTemperature += 0.5;
      updateTemperature();
      if (!document.getElementById("heater-audio").paused) {
        document.getElementById("heater-audio").pause();
        document.getElementById("heater-audio").currentTime = 0;
      }
      document.getElementById("heater-audio").play();
    }
    if (boilerTemperature > 100) {
      document.getElementById("steam-whistle-button").disabled = false;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("steam-whistle-button").disabled = true;
    }
  }, 250);
}

function stopTemperatureIncrease() {
  clearInterval(temperatureIntervalId);
  temperatureIntervalId = null;
}

function toggleHeater() {
  boilerHeater = !boilerHeater;
  updateHeaterStatus();
  if (boilerHeater) {
    startTemperatureIncrease();
  } else {
    stopTemperatureIncrease();
    document.getElementById("steam-whistle-button").disabled = true;
  }
}

function playSteamWhistle() {
  if (boilerTemperature > 100) {
    steamWhistleSound.play();
    boilerTemperature -= 5;
    updateTemperature();
  }
}

updateTemperature();
updateHeaterStatus();
document.getElementById("steam-whistle-button").disabled = true;
```

Thank you

Comment: The code for increase seems fine on the first glance. Create a second interval which dies the decrease, similar to the already exiting one. Depending on the status of the boiler (on/off) start one interval and stop the other...

Comment: I already tried that out but whenever I do it, it seems to not work and also stop the increase work so both of them don't work

Comment: Then you obviously did it wrong... But unless you show what you did, it's impossible to help you